# Updation from Stored Procedure Working but Not Working from UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, user-interface, stored-procedures

My Submit Button action:

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=172.25.192.80;Initial Catalog=DB01HMS001;User ID=pj01hms001;Password=tcshyd");
        con.Open();


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_team5_customerupdate", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", Convert.ToString(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname",lstname.Text);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StreetAddress", streetadd.Text);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", Eaddress.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", txtstate.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TownorCity",towncity.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zipcode", Convert.ToInt32(txtzipcode.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNumber",Convert.ToInt64(mblenum.Text));

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", Convert.ToInt64(phnenum.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", cname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficeAddress", Oaddress.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custid", Convert.ToInt64(Session["cusid"]));
        Response.Write(Convert.ToString(Session["cusid"]));
        int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (a == 1) {

            Response.Write("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Failure");
        }

        con.Close();
    }
```

My Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[team5_customerprofile] (
[CustomerProfileID]       INT           IDENTITY (1001, 1) NOT NULL,
[CustomerID]              AS            (CONVERT([bigint],CONVERT([varchar],[CustomerProfileID],0)+CONVERT([varchar](15),getdate(),(112)),0)),
[Password]                VARCHAR (20)  NULL,
[Title]                   VARCHAR (20)  NULL,
[Firstname]               VARCHAR (20)  NULL,
[Lastname]                VARCHAR (20)  NULL,
[DateOfBirth]             DATE          NULL,
[Gender]                  BIT           NULL,
[StreetAddress]           VARCHAR (100) NULL,
[Nationality]             VARCHAR (20)  NULL,
[State]                   VARCHAR (30)  NULL,
[TownorCity]              VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Zipcode]                 INT           NULL,
[MobileNumber]            BIGINT        NULL,
[AlternatePhone]          BIGINT        NULL,
[PhoneNumber]             BIGINT        NULL,
[EmailAddress]            VARCHAR (30)  NULL,
[CompanyName]             VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[OfficeAddress]           VARCHAR (100) NULL,
[TotalBonusMilesAcheived] INT           DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
CHECK ([Title]='Mrs.' OR [Title]='Miss.' OR [Title]='Mr.'),
CHECK ([Nationality]='Indian'),
CHECK (len([Zipcode])=(6))
);
```

I have written a Stored Procedure, shown below, which updates the Table on executing it externally but it does not update the table when i try to enter the values through the UI and press Submit.

```
CREATE procedure usp_team5_customerupdate
   (
   @Title varchar(20),
   @Lastname varchar(20),
   @StreetAddress varchar(100),
   @State varchar(30),
   @TownorCity varchar(50),
   @Zipcode int,
   @MobileNumber bigint,
   @PhoneNumber bigint,
   @EmailAddress varchar(30),
   @CompanyName varchar(50),
   @OfficeAddress varchar(100),
   @custid nvarchar(20)
   )
   as     
   begin
   update team5_customerprofile
   set
   Title=@Title,Lastname=@Lastname,     
   StreetAddress=@StreetAddress,
   [State]=@State,
   TownorCity=@TownorCity,     
   Zipcode=@Zipcode,
   MobileNumber=@MobileNumber,
   PhoneNumber=@PhoneNumber,     
   EmailAddress=@EmailAddress,
   CompanyName=@CompanyName,     
   OfficeAddress=@OfficeAddress
   where
   CustomerID=@custid
   end
```

Comment: Do you get an exception or error when executing the script via button click?

Comment: No Exception, No Error. Nothing. Even "ExecuteNonQuery()" is returning 1 which indicates that the query executed successfully. "Success" is also getting Displayed. No Database Update is done even after that. :(

Comment: try creating transaction and commiting transaction around your update statement. Transaction may have closed

Comment: SamarpanBiswas what is the value of @custid ? Can you check, this is null,so it is not updating

Comment: Simplest troubleshooting: run SQL Profiler, select SP profile and watch real sql updates that happen in the database on the button click. Then run sp manually and compare events.

Answer (score 0):

Change the datatype for the `CustId` in the stored procedure to match the column datatype which is `BigInt`

```
 @custid nvarchar(20)
```

Also in your code just pass the `CustId` without any conversion.

And finally you can put a debugger and replace check the values in your code for each variable and use it in the SQL query window and run the below to debug the error.

```
DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @qry = '
        UPDATE team5_customerprofile
        set
        Title=''' + @Title + '''
       where
       CustomerID=' + @custid + '
     end';
PRINT @qry;
```

You can include the other columns so when this runs you can check where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create procedure usp_team5_customerupdate        
(  
@Title varchar(20),  
@Lastname varchar(20),  
@StreetAddress varchar(100),  
@State varchar(30),  
@TownorCity varchar(50),  
@Zipcode int =0,  
@MobileNumber bigint ,  
@PhoneNumber bigint,  
@EmailAddress varchar(30),  
@CompanyName varchar(50),  
@OfficeAddress varchar(100),  
@custid nvarchar(20)  
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
IF Exists(SELECT * FROM team5_customerprofile WHERE CustomerID=@custid)  
BEGIN  
   UPDATE team5_customerprofile  
SET  
Title=@Title,Lastname=@Lastname,  
StreetAddress=@StreetAddress,  
[State]=@State,  
TownorCity=@TownorCity,  
Zipcode=@Zipcode,  
MobileNumber=@MobileNumber,  
PhoneNumber=@PhoneNumber,  
EmailAddress=@EmailAddress,  
CompanyName=@CompanyName,  
OfficeAddress=@OfficeAddress  
WHERE CustomerID=@custid  
END
   ELSE  
     BEGIN  
          PRINT 'Invalid Customer Id '''+@custid+''''  
     END  
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written the code is correct and the stored proc is also correct check the connection string and run the SQL-Profiler check all parameters if there is any conversion issues check out all ...

Try to alter this procedure once and if u get any error while execute this code let me know ...

```
 CREATE procedure usp_team5_customerupdate

 @Title varchar(20),
 @Lastname varchar(20),
 @StreetAddress varchar(100),
 @State varchar(30),
 @TownorCity varchar(50),
 @Zipcode int,
 @MobileNumber bigint,
 @PhoneNumber bigint,
 @EmailAddress varchar(30),
 @CompanyName varchar(50),
 @OfficeAddress varchar(100),
 @custid nvarchar(20)

 as     
 begin
 IF Exists(SELECT * FROM team5_customerprofile WHERE CustomerID=@custid)  
 BEGIN  
 update team5_customerprofile
 set
 Title=@Title,Lastname=@Lastname,     
 StreetAddress=@StreetAddress,
 State=@State,
 TownorCity=@TownorCity,     
 Zipcode=@Zipcode,
 MobileNumber=@MobileNumber,
 PhoneNumber=@PhoneNumber,     
 EmailAddress=@EmailAddress,
 CompanyName=@CompanyName,     
 OfficeAddress=@OfficeAddress
 where
 CustomerID=@custid

 end
 else
 print 'Error'
 end

 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the parameters being passed along with the querystring, i.e.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_team5_customerupdate", con);
```

Try Passing parameters like:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_team5_customerupdate @Title,@Lastname..(So on)", con);
```